# Databinding WPF Rectangle gradient fill

Tags: binding

I'm attempting to databind a gradient brush as a Rectangle fill. What do I need to do to get the commented-out binding to work?  StartColor and EndColor are declared as System.Drawing.Color.

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="20">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <LinearGradientBrush>
      <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Pink"/>
      <GradientStop Offset="1"  Color="Red"/>
      <!--<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{Binding Path=StartColor}"/>-->
      <!--<GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{Binding Path=EndColor}" />-->
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220688/databinding-the-color-of-a-radialgradient-brush-in-silverlight-3

Answer (score 2):

The problem was using System.Drawing.Color rather than the proper System.Windows.Media.Color