# Dynamically change gradientstop color

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm using a windows phone silverlight application, the default panorama template has a listbox with a static gradientstop property.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding lbox}" Name="listboxUsers" Margin="2,126,0,6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
<SNIP>
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" Name="Recta">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1"  />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
      </Rectangle>
```

I want to change the color property of the gradientstop dynamically , I tried to bind the Color property:

```
public class lbox   
{

    public lbox(string par1, string par2, Color par4) 
    { 
        displayname = par1;
        state = par2;  

        gscolor = new GradientStop();
        gscolor.Color = par4;
    }

    public string displayname { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush lbcolor { get; set; }
    private GradientStop gscolor { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
GradientStop Color="{Binding gscolor}" Offset="1"  />
```

However, this causes a XMLPaseException: AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE. I also tried to use a color  property without a new instance of Gradientstop in the code behind... Note that the binding is working correctly for string values.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**
Matt pointed me in the right direction:

```
<Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" Fill="{Binding lbcolor}">
```

In the code behind as seen above, lbcolor is a `SolidColorBrush`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible.

See reason why at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickkramer/archive/2006/08/18/705116.aspx

This is discussed in depth at http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/111477/254754.aspx

There is a possible work around in the answer to [Databinding the color of a RadialGradient brush in silverlight 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220688/databinding-the-color-of-a-radialgradient-brush-in-silverlight-3)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just need to set `gscolor` as a `Color` rather than `GradientStop`.  You are assigning a `GradientStop` to a `Color` object in your XAML.  Or, you should bind to the `Color` property of `gscolor`.

`Color = "{Binding gscolor.Color}"`

Comment: I did try that using a object: 
 public object picColor { get; set; }
 picColor = gscolor.Color;

But this causes the same exception, as mentioned in my first post, I did try to use a default Color property with argb. Unfortunatly this also didn't work. Is it possible to bind the whole gradientstop value? 

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `Color="{Binding gscolor.Color}"`?  And if so, do you still get the error?

Comment: Didn't think this value was accessible in XAML, it isnt in the code behind without creating a new instance. Just tried it but still the same error occurs... Thanks so far

Comment: Ok, add a new `Color` property and try using the new variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Animazioni
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            el.Opacity = 0.5;
            el.Height = 100;
            el.Width = 100;

        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RadialGradientBrush _rgb = new RadialGradientBrush();
            GradientStop gs1 = new GradientStop();
            GradientStop gs2 = new GradientStop();
            GradientStop gs3 = new GradientStop();

            gs1.Offset = 0;
            gs2.Offset = 0.7;
            gs3.Offset = 1;

            gs1.Color = Colors.Yellow;
            gs2.Color = Colors.Orange;
            gs3.Color = Colors.Red;

           //

            _rgb.GradientStops.Add(gs1);
            _rgb.GradientStops.Add(gs2);
            _rgb.GradientStops.Add(gs3);
            el.Fill = _rgb;

            myCanvas.Children.Add(el);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain the code you posted. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 0):

I Do know that This is older than me , but i ran into the same issue. I had the Color in a DynamicResource and Storyboard animation was changing the value so the dynamicresource was getting lost. So i tried to figure out how to do it, and i ended up using Storyboard ColorAnimation programmatically.

The given Example is for 2 GradientStops

xHeader = The element the gradientstops belongs to.

And also there's a static function RandomString that is generating RandomStrings for the Storyboard name.

You would also change the PropertyPath there..

```
 public void AnimateHeader(Color First, Color Second, Double DurationSecs=0.2)
    {
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DurationSecs));
        ColorAnimation FirstAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
        ColorAnimation SecondAnimation = new ColorAnimation();

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(FirstAnimation);
        sb.Children.Add(SecondAnimation);
        FirstAnimation.Duration = duration;
        FirstAnimation.To = First;
        FirstAnimation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1);
        SecondAnimation.Duration = duration;
        SecondAnimation.To = Second;
        SecondAnimation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(FirstAnimation, xHeader);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(FirstAnimation, new PropertyPath("Foreground.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(SecondAnimation, xHeader);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(SecondAnimation, new PropertyPath("Foreground.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"));

        Resources.Add(RandomString(100)+(new DateTime()).Ticks, sb);
        sb.Completed += (o, s) => { Resources.Remove(sb); };
        sb.Begin();
    }
```