# Getting AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE while data binding in WP7 User control

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I have created a user control in Silverlight which basically animates the size of a rectangle.

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Gray"><StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard" Completed="myStoryboard_Completed">
            <DoubleAnimation x:Name="ExpandY" From="{Binding Path=From}" To="{Binding Path=To}" Duration="00:00:2" 
            Storyboard.TargetName="myScaleTransform" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <BackEase Amplitude="0.0" EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>            
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Rectangle  x:Name="myRectangle" MouseLeftButtonDown="Mouse_Clicked" 
 Fill="{Binding Path=Barcolor}" Width="35" Height="50" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"  MouseEnter="myRectangle_MouseEnter" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="0" MouseLeave="myRectangle_MouseLeave">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="myScaleTransform" CenterY="50"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```

I have bound an object which implements INotifyPropertyChanged to this as the data context.

Now, the whole thing works fine when I run it as a silverlight control in an ASP.NET host page. But when I port the same code to create a WP7 user control I get the AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE pointing to the location where From="{Binding Path=From}"  is located in the Double animation  "ExpandY".

Is there anything different how the data is bound in a silverlight control and a WP7 user control?

Comment: What is the DataContext? is From dependency property?

Comment: Sorry - but I just added this XAML to an example page - and it opens fine. Maybe - are you using sample data in the designer? Is this returning something invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `DoubleAnimation` is not a `FrameworkElement` and in Silverlight for WP7 you can only set a binding on a `FrameworkElement`. In order to achieve this effect you'll need to manipulate the animation in code-behind, possibly by wrapping the behavior up into a separate `UserControl`.

Same as this question: [Binding to 'To' In Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002421/binding-to-to-in-storyboard)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your tags I'm assuming that you're using SL4 on the web version. WP7 is based on Silverlight 3 and doesn't support binding in exactly the same way.

I suspect your problem is due to the same as in [Dynamically change gradientstop color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076683/dynamically-change-gradientstop-color)

Comment: Hi Matt, the issue is occuring for the Binding Elements From, To also.